# How do I add docs other than README in a Play 2.0 Scala binary distribution?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play Framework 2.0 Scala, it automatically adds the README to the binary dist. How can I add other docs? For example, I have a HOWTO.develop doc as well that I want included.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `dist` task is very limited.

It only takes the dependencies (JARs), the `start` script, the config files and the `README` file, so there is no easy way to add something else if the generated zip. ([source](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.0/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayCommands.scala#L240))