# Play 2.x: How to deploy scripts with distributable package

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm creating a project in Play 2.1 and plan on distributing the project as a self-contained package using `play dist`.  However, I need some extra scripts that are accessible to the server and can make use of the project's libraries (models, mostly).  An example of a script I need is a task that will be ran as a cron job to collect data from an external device.

In Rails or any other web framework I'm used to, I would create a scripts directory and put anything like this there.  However, I'm fairly new to Java and this framework, so I don't know what the convention is, if any, and there's a hard requirement not to distribute uncompiled source.

Looking through Play's documentation on [creating a standalone version](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ProductionDist), I see that the final result is a directory with a lib directory and a start script.  Ideally, the solution to my problem would be to have play generate another script of my choosing next to that start script:

```
my-application
 └ lib
    └ *.jar
 └ start
 └ new_script
```

Any suggestions or options I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question at "[How do I add docs other than README in a Play 2.0 Scala binary distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780393/how-do-i-add-docs-other-than-readme-in-a-play-2-0-scala-binary-distribution)". It appears there is nothing out-of-the-box like you're thinking. So far, I have overcome this by writing a bash script that unpacks the zip, adds what I need, and then bundles it back up as a tar.gz file.

- For one thing, the start script doesn't have the executable bit turned on. This was annoying when I handed it to someone for testing.
- It doesn't include a bat for running on windows, so I'm working on that
- I can very much see needing scripts included like you in the future

(I would have tried zip, but couldn't figure it out from the command line.)

I would offer to patch play, but they seem to move swiftly at adding new features versus maintenance. I built my app against 2.0 and it won't even work with 2.0.4. Not sure how I can patch version 2.0 and upgrade to use my own patch.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Greg.  So far I've ended up writing a short bash script to write a start.bat file for Windows and resolve the execution bit on the unix start script.  I'm thinking that packing another shell wrapper in the distributable that uses the lib/* dir in its classpath should be able to execute arbitrary classes.